# signed/unsigned int type in llvmlite

Tags: python, llvmlite

I am trying to use llvmlite, this is what llvmlite documentation say about `IntType`:

> ### `class llvmlite.ir.IntType(bits)`
>
> The type of integers. The Python integer bits specifies the bitwidth of the integers having this type.
>
> #### `width`
>
> The width in bits.

Is it signed or unsigned int? How can I use the other type of int (eg. if `IntType` is signed, then how to make unsigned variable)? *Is it possible?*

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519005/how-to-distinguish-signed-and-unsigned-integer-in-llvm